# Увеличение итераций

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Оба следующих кода возвращают комментарии к одному посту со стены. Разница в том, что первый однократно возвращает 100 комментариев к посту, а второй — до 2500. Вопрос заключается в переносе этой 25-кратной итерации в первый код, так как с первым кодом можно также извлекать комментарии отдельного пользователя по его айди и кроме того — обращаться к посту без указания его айди — по номеру, тогда как второму коду в аргументах требуется точный айди поста.

КОД №1:

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var user_id = Args.user_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var post_count = Args.post_count;

if (post_count == null)
    post_count = 1;         // НА ОБРАБОТКЕ 1 ПОСТ

// Получаем список постов
var posts = API.wall.get({
    "owner_id": owner_id,
    "offset": offset,
    "count" : 100,
});

var i = 0;
var userComments = {};

while(i < posts.items.length && i < post_count)
{
    var post_id = posts.items[i].id;
    var comments = API.wall.getComments({
        "owner_id": owner_id,
        "post_id": post_id,
        "offset": 0,
        "count" : 100, // максимально возможное количество коментов, 
                       // кот. можно получить с одного вызова
    });

    var j = 0;
    while(j < comments.items.length)
    {
        if (user_id == null || comments.items[j].from_id == user_id)
            userComments.push(comments.items[j]);

        j = j + 1;
    }

    i = i + 1;
}

return userComments;
```

КОД №2:

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var post_id = Args.post_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var count = Args.count;

if(post_id == null || owner_id == null){
    return {"count": 0, "items": []};  // Если параметры не заданы, возвращаем пустой массив
}
if(count == null){
    count = 10; // Значение по умолчанию
}
if(offset == null){
    offset = 0; // Значение по умолчанию
}
var i = 0;
var items = [];
while(i < 25 && count > items.length){
    var cur_count = count - items.length;
    if(cur_count > 100){
        cur_count = 100;
    }
    items = items + API.wall.getComments({"owner_id": owner_id, "post_id": post_id, "offset": offset+100*i, "count": cur_count, "need_likes":1})["items"];
    i = i + 1;
}
return {"count": items.length, "items": items};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю, что-то вроде кода ниже должно сработать

Попутные замечания

- стоит поправить стиль: в js обычно используется camelCase в именах переменных, а не python_style. У вас смешаны оба стиля (хотя питоновский стиль преобладает)
- для сравнения значений в js лучше использовать `===`, а не `==`
- возможно, стоит `tries_count` сделать так же входным параметром (`Args.tries_count`): это позволит варьировать количество скачиваемых комментов
- стоило бы не тупо слать 25 запросов, а проверять ответ, и получив пустой ответ прекращать нагружать сеть

Сильно менять код под своё видение я не стал, чтоб внесённые изменения были виднее/очевиднее, к тому же я не в контексте вашего проекта; если захотите - поменяете сами. тут есть что улучшить...

```
var owner_id = Args.owner_id;
var user_id = Args.user_id;
var offset = Args.offset;
var post_count = Args.post_count;
var comments_count = Args.comments_count;

if (post_count == null)
    post_count = 1;         // НА ОБРАБОТКЕ 1 ПОСТ

// Получаем список постов
var posts = API.wall.get({
    "owner_id": owner_id,
    "offset": offset,
    "count" : 100,
});

var postIndex = 0;
var userComments = {};

while(postIndex < posts.items.length && postIndex < post_count)
{
    var post_id = posts.items[postIndex].id;

    var tries_count = 25;
    var try_nmb = 0;
    var comments = [];
    while (comments.length < comments_count && try_nmb < tries_count)
    {
        comments = comments + API.wall.getComments({
                        "owner_id": owner_id,
                        "post_id": post_id,
                        "offset": offset+100*try_nmb,
                        "count": 100,
                        "need_likes":1})["items"];
        try_nmb = try_nmb + 1;
    }

    var commentIndex = 0;
    while(commentIndex < comments.length)
    {
        if (user_id == null || comments[commentIndex].from_id == user_id)
            userComments.push(comments[commentIndex]);
        commentIndex = commentIndex + 1;
    }
    postIndex = postIndex + 1;
}

return userComments;
```

Comment: Павел, при попытке сохранения процедуры возникает ошибка по поводу `cur_count` —
 https://www.radikal.kz/images/2018/03/13/BEZYMYNNYI1d970ed3e3604c1c.png Видимо, по той же причине и не запускается.

Закомментирование и замены на comments_count и post_count — результата не дали))

Comment: действительно, оставил `cur_count` в одном месте. поправил.

Comment: А сейчас пишет **error in line 35: ';' expected, '+=' found**. Это строка: **try_nmb += 1;**

Comment: хех. вернул обратно `try_nmb = try_nmb + 1`

Comment: Павел, к сожалению, код по-прежнему однократно выводит лишь сотню комментариев к посту, хотя в примере не было и пятисот (а ожидалось — до двух тысяч пятисот). Проверял так: **owner_id=-60312130**, **offset=0**, **comments_count=1**, остальные поля оставлял пустыми. С другими цифрами иногда приходила ошибка.

Comment: `comments_count=1` --> срабатывает условие `comments.length < comments_count`: после скачивания первой порции комментов `comments.length` равно 100, это больше 1, поэтому выполнение цикла прекращается. Попробуйте `comments_count=200`. Я так понял, в случае больших чисел вы получаете отлуп из-за превышения разрешённого числа запросов в секунду. Это можно решить, например, выполняя запросы пореже (ждать между запросами сколько нужно, к примеру 0,334 секунды). Но тут решение нужно искать учитывая контекст вашего приложения, а я его не знаю.

Comment: Тоже не пошло. И надо сказать, что частота запросов не причём, потому что я процедуру однократно запускаю, и всё равно в рамках этого одного вызова выводится, что **"Too many requests per second"**, хотя второй второй код, который приводил в вопросе — возвращает до 25 тысяч. Может дело в трёхкратном `while`?

Comment: Олег, вроде действительно, возвращает не больше 400. Но то же самое можно было сделать с первым кодом из вопроса, продублировав соответствующий участок четыре раза, с нужным смещением по `offset`, а хотелось, как во втором коде — до 2500. Что ж, наверное, подпрограммы получения постов и извлечения юзера по айди — не дают увеличить количество итераций. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ, я его отмечю.